# Is there a standard terminology for the $A_c = \sqrt{A_1 \cdot A_2}$ where $A_1 = A_x(x,y)$ and $A_2 = A_y(x,y)$?

Tags: products

$A$ is a spatially variant function in 2D space.

$A_1$ is a function calculated by varying at $x = x_1$, and $A_2$ is a function calculated by varying at $y = y_1$. Then, I want to estimate $A_c$ at $x = x_1$ and $y = y_1$ by evaluating it for $\sqrt{A_1A_2}$. Would this be called a spatial convolution? What is the standard terminology for a procedure as this?

EDIT:

Let me make this a bit more clear:

$$A_1(x_1) = \int{\phi_1(x,y)dS}  \\
A_2(y_1) = \int{\phi_2(x,y)dS} $$

Then, I estimate $A_c$ as

$$A_c(x_1,y_1) = \sqrt{A_1(x_1)A_2(y_1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

This looks like $A_c$ is the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of $A_1$ and $A_2$.